# How do I configure IIS 6.2 to handle Ajax requests

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis

I have a web application that is currently running on a windows server running IIS 6.2.  I am not trying to migrate into a new environment.  I have the application up and running but the ajax calls are not working yet.

When I hit the following URL on my working production server I am returned a page with a bunch of script:

https://myURL/ajax/MyAssembly.OrderInformationService,MyWeb.ashx

However, when I hit the same URL on my new server I get a 404:
https://MyNewURL/ajax/MyAssembly.OrderInformationService,MyWeb.ashx

Both servers have the same handler mappings and handler mappings enabled for ashx.  Is there something else I need to install or enable on the server to handle these AJAX requests?

The /ajax/ folder is not a real folder and does not exist on either server.  I'm not really sure how this setup works.  Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the application pool from Integrated to Classic and everything is working.  This mirrors the setup I have in production.  I overlooked this setting...

I hope this helps someone else.